# Query with temp table can't execute without SET FMTONLY OFF

Tags: sql, sql-server, fastreport

SQL Set FMTOnly OFF by Default, i figured out that fast report doesn't respect default, so i put it off manually in my procedures, now i want to understand
why storage procedures with temp tables don't work when FMTOnly is o.
Someone can explain this please? Thx.

Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Procedure SP_Fast_Obter_Relatorio, 
Line 54 Invalid object name '#Temp'.

[Query and result when FMTOnly is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjtCT.jpg)

[Query and result when FMTOnly is OFF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Swy86.jpg)

Comment: Because `FMTONLY ON` doesn't execute statements, so any statement that relies on the (non-existent) temp table will fail to parse. There are [workarounds](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2b64ca7a-b525-4b64-b4ad-e3c9b7dea5cb/hot-to-get-current-value-of-fmtonly?forum=transactsql) for this if you must support client tools that use `FMTONLY ON` to discover metadata (where you sneakily turn it off again).

Comment: These workarounds helped me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the manual: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-fmtonly-transact-sql

`FMTONLY ON` only returns metadata to the client. Not result rows or temp information.

> Returns only metadata to the client. Can be used to test the format of the response without actually running the query.
>
> The setting causes the statement to return the column information only; no rows of data are returned.